# Django view to process a formset with only serialized data

Tags: django, django-views

How do I write a view that processes forms in a formset?

I have a view that renders a form to page. It get's data from POST.

```
    SurveyFormset = formset_factory(SurveyForm, extra=0)
    survey_formset = SurveyFormset(initial=data)
```

On that page I have some jQuery/ajax that serializes the form and passes it to a view...

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
      var form = $('#surveyset'); 

      form.submit( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax( {
          type: "POST",
          url: form.attr( 'action' ),
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

In this second view, how do I save all the forms in my formset?

```
def save_survey_set(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # How do I save all the data from forms as new Surveys
        return HttpResponse('saved/updated') # Redirect to a 'success' page
```

Comment: Sorry, cant understand the issue. What exactly is the problem. Are you getting some error? What is happening?

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb Sorry, I'll try to make it more clear with some edits.